# Webpack perform some post build script task

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, webpack, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin

I amusing webpack to generate bundle for my application. After bundle is generated, I need to perform following task.

1. Open the bundle file and rename certain path. Because of the way we have setup put website, I am forced to change the path in the bundle we have created. Currently I am manually changing the path. So basically I am looking to run a task which will look for XXXX text and replace it with YYYY in the bundle.
2. After I rename the keys/text, I want to uglify the content to minify the file.

What options do I have. I am new to webpack and I am looking for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader)?

I would use this to run a "replace" task after you've generated your bundle. Essentially, this automates what you are currently doing.

Comment: This looks promising. Can you please tell me how can I tell webpack to run it only after after file is generated?

Comment: The examples on the npm page are pretty straighforward. I would try them out with your current setup. 

Also, since this is replacing the relevant text for you while it bundles it, running a task "after" does not apply to you.

Comment: it seems it only works on JS file and not on CSS files.